# Why doesn't the dependency contain a jar in the maven public repository https://mvnrepository.com?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-central, jackson-dataformats-text

I a maven rookie and am wondering how to get a binary jar file if it is not already in the repo. Specifically i'm in need of: jackson-dataformats-text-2.13.0.jar. Do I need to build it myself? I'm used to creating a project and marking a library as a dependency and seeing the jar downloaded into my .m2 cache but all i see in my cache is:

```
jchan@jchan-Z170N:~/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/jackson-dataformats-text/2.13.0$ ls
jackson-dataformats-text-2.13.0.jar.lastUpdated  jackson-dataformats-text-2.13.0.pom.sha1
jackson-dataformats-text-2.13.0.pom              _remote.repositories
```

Can someone advise how I am to get a built version of the jar from maven central?

We are still maintaining our ant build and I need the jar file for this. (i know i know, ancient stuff but team is not ready to port just yet).

Comment: I mavenized monsters. Let's try if you want in a fork of your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### parent pom don't contain jar file

This is the reason why no bundle link is present on the official public maven repository https://mvnrepository.com

The maven dependency is not a jar, is a parent. So the extension is: **.pom** which is just a plain **pom.xml**

Parent dependencies don't contain compiled class like .jar.

[image: maven]

In your specific case, there are another dependencies who contains jars:

- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml/2.13.0/
- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml/2.13.0/

### advice

Check what classes do you need on your ant project and search if exist a jar (with the classes you need) on https://mvnrepository.com

Another option is to get all the dependencies from pom :
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/jackson-dataformats-text/2.9.0/jackson-dataformats-text-2.9.0.pom and download them into your ant project. In theory is the same of add the parent pom in a maven project